# error: field 'ctx' has incomplete type EVP_CIPHER_CTX

Tags: linux, openssl, debian, freeswitch

Problem: I need to install Cepstral (tts engine) into Freeswitch running Debian 8. Freeswitch is already up and running, but I needed to build it from source in order for it create the mod_cepstral module.

When I run `make` this is the error I get:

```
In file included from ./crypto/include/prng.h:17:0,
                 from ./crypto/include/crypto_kernel.h:50,
                 from ./include/srtp.h:53,
                 from srtp/srtp.c:46:
./crypto/include/aes_icm_ossl.h:66:20: error: field ‘ctx’ has incomplete type
     EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
                    ^~~
In file included from srtp/srtp.c:50:0:
./crypto/include/aes_gcm_ossl.h:58:18: error: field ‘ctx’ has incomplete type
   EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
                  ^~~
Makefile:646: recipe for target 'srtp.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [srtp.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/freeswitch/libs/srtp'
Makefile:3931: recipe for target 'libs/srtp/libsrtp.la' failed
make: *** [libs/srtp/libsrtp.la] Error 2
```

I have been scouring the internet for solutions, but I am not a developer and this is way over my head. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with support at Cepstral, we determined that Jessie (Debian 8) is not yet fully compatible. I rebuilt the server with Debian 7 and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 30):

cause newer OpenSSL don't expose **struct EVP_CIPHER_CTX** ,

try this

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
//do sth here
//...
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

Comment: Which file contain this code or where to change it ?

Comment: @DumitruBoaghi, did you resolve this error ?

Comment: I am annoyed to have to make this change to everywhere in my old code (in fact i don't have time and it's blocking me from doing other things because of that)... and it's not just as simple as putting a .._free if you have return statements scattered through that now need this added code.

Answer (score 9):

```
wget https://github.com/cisco/libsrtp/archive/v2.1.0.tar.gz
tar xfv v2.1.0.tar.gz
cd libsrtp-2.1.0
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-openssl
make shared_library && sudo make install
```

Get the latest version of `libsrtp`.

Comment: Please explain why the code above should resolve this situation.

Comment: This isn't a solution for me. The structure shouldn't be exposed. The right way is to use the SSL context the right way. See the 'Xt Z' solution below.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that there is a dependency on OpenSSL, but the version of OpenSSL you are using is incompatible. You are using OpenSSL 1.1.0 but you need to use OpenSSL 1.0.2

Comment: Just installed 1.1.0 and tested it, but still getting the same error

Comment: As I said in my answer you need to use 1.0.2 *not* 1.1.0. The errors above result from a mismatch between an application expecting 1.0.2, but using 1.1.0 headers.

Comment: yeah I thought I had installed 1.0.2 (above comment was a typo) and still failed but after checking I realized the the install did not quite take. Reinstalling now to test again.

Comment: Ok so 1.0.2 is installed but still getting the ctx error

Comment: @Joe did you resolve this error? I am still getting after installing 1.0.2 openssl.

Comment: @Prateek  The answer below was from me. At the time Cepstral was not supported on Debian 8. I had to downgrade and it worked. However, it has been 3+ years so that may not be the issue you are having.

Comment: @Joe, I am trying on Ubuntu 20.04 and freeswitch 1.6.14. Facing this same error there. Could it be because of incompatibility in ubuntu and freeswitch versions?

Comment: @Prateek  possibly. Maybe downgrade one version back. Honestly, I haven't touched freeswitch in a few years now so I can't be of much help