# I keep getting this error of "storage size of 'ctx isn't known for EVP_CIPHER_CTX

Tags: c, openssl

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
```

trying to crypt a word dictionary to find key

Keep getting segmentation faults or storage error

Comment: This means the definition of the structure is not found. You may want to include the proper header file(s)

Comment: Sometimes, APIs do not share context structure as is. You are expected to call an init function to get a pointer to a new one which is created by the API itself. Then you pass that pointer to subsequent calls to the API

Comment: Pretty sure I had this same issue once. IIRC, Openssl used to make this struct definition public but then made it private.

Comment: There are multiple related questions on this topic with newer versions of OpenSSL starting with 1.1.x ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518843/error-field-ctx-has-incomplete-type-evp-cipher-ctx)).

Answer (score 4):

Starting with version 1.1 of OpenSSL, `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` became an opaque structure, and `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init` is now an alias for `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset` which clears an existing structure.

You need to instead use `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new` to allocate space for one.

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
...
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```